# How to apply some operation on many dictionaries (or: how ot modify dictionaries within a for loop) in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

If I have many dictionaries that I would like to modify (e.g., to filter out some value in all of them), how can I proceed in a efficient/pythonic way?

In the following example, the filtering operation within the loop works, but the actual dictionaries are not changed/affected:

```
d1 = {key:val for key, val in zip(('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), range(5))}
d2 = {key:val for key, val in zip(('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), range(4, 9))}

for d in (d1, d2):
    print d
    d = {key: d[key] for key in d if d[key] != 4}
    print d
print d1
print d2

# {'a': 0, 'c': 2, 'b': 1, 'e': 4, 'd': 3}
# {'a': 0, 'c': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 3}
# {'a': 4, 'c': 6, 'b': 5, 'e': 8, 'd': 7}
# {'c': 6, 'b': 5, 'e': 8, 'd': 7}
# {'a': 0, 'c': 2, 'b': 1, 'e': 4, 'd': 3}
# {'a': 4, 'c': 6, 'b': 5, 'e': 8, 'd': 7}
```

Comment: They're not affected because you're not changing them. the variable called 'd' is a new variable which have nothing in common with your dics **d1** and **d2**.

Comment: Indeed - this is why I am asking a way to actually change them ;-) Is there any semantic that allow to actually directly work on the dict objects and not on an intermediate variable?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
d1 = {key:val for key, val in zip(('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), range(5))}
d2 = {key:val for key, val in zip(('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), range(4, 9))}

dicts = [d1, d2]

print dicts
#[{'a': 0, 'c': 2, 'b': 1, 'e': 4, 'd': 3}, {'a': 4, 'c': 6, 'b': 5, 'e': 8, 'd': 7}]

for i, d in enumerate(dicts):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if v == 4:
            del dicts[i][k]

print dicts
#[{'a': 0, 'c': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 3}, {'c': 6, 'b': 5, 'e': 8, 'd': 7}]
print d1
#{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3}
print d2
#{'b': 5, 'c': 6, 'd': 7, 'e': 8}
```

Comment: Thanks! Unless I am wrong, the `enumerate` and the `dicts[i]` parts are not needed. You could already iterate over `for d in dicts` and do directly `del d[k]` I think, as indeed thanks to `del` you directly act on the object within the loop and not on an intermediate variable. So thanks, it woks! I would be suprised there is no more direct way to achieve that in Python...??